# Debugdiag not working with Windows store apps

Tags: debugdiag

Trying "monitor for leaks" with any windows store app (including the built-in apps) using debugdiag2 update 2 fails.

I get a "Failed to monitor for leaks in .... Please make sure that everyone has read and execute permissions for ...leaktest.dll" message.

I've changed the permissions as indicated and followed the suggestion at:

[Troubleshooting native memory leaks in Windows Store applications using DebugDiag and LeakTrack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21462880/troubleshooting-native-memory-leaks-in-windows-store-applications-using-debugdia)

But no luck.

Works fine for non store apps.

Anyone have this working?